# How to distribute maven libraries from a pom.xml?

Tags: xml, maven, intellij-idea

I have a pom.xml which contains a couple of libraries which is parsed by Intellij Idea for development. Usually these libraries are downloaded to a personal maven directory.
Now I want to copy automatically all these libraries to a distribution directory. How is this possible?

It would be also nice to have a possibility that the distribution directory is cleaned when there are older versions in place.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need an in-house repository manager.

Two commercial products are `Nexus` and `Artifactory`.

How it works. Set up your repository manager on a server (repo.internal.mycompany.com). Configure your settings.xml with credentials for the repo. Maven builds will now deploy artifacts to the repository manager, which are searchable and downloadable by other developers within your organisation.

Additionally, the internal repo can act as a proxy for maven central artifacts.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, will check these. However for the moment I am fine with the copy-dependencies plugin from maven.

Answer (score 0):

The **maven-dependency-plugin** is solving this for the moment. This plugin offers a functionality to copy all dependencies. Below is a simple example of a configuration:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.lib.dir</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```